# why aren't pandas "rank" percentiles bounded between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, pandas, rank, percentile

I use pandas frequently and often execute code comparable to the following:

```
df['var_rank'] = df['var'].rank(pct=True)
print( df.var_rank.max() )
```

And will often get values greater than 1. It still happens whether I keep or drop 'na' values. This is obviously easy to fix (just divide by the value with the largest rank), so I'm not asking for a work-around. I'm just curious why this happens and haven't found any clues online.

Anyone know why this happens?

Some very simple example data [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21734889/test_df) (dropbox link - pickled pandas series).

I get a value of 1.0156 from `df.rank(pct=True).max()`. I've had other data with values as high as 4 or 5. I'm usually using pretty messy data.

Comment: Please can you post some sample data which gives you values greater than 1?

Comment: Edited the question with link to some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad data.

```
>>> s.rank(pct=True).max()
1.015625

s.sort(inplace=True)
>>> s.tail(7)
8      202512882
6      253661077
102            -
101            -
99             -
58             -
116            -
Name: Total Assets, dtype: object

>>> s[s != u'-'].rank(pct=True).max()
1.0
```

In Pandas 0.18.0 (released last week), you can specify [numeric only](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
s.rank(pct=True, numeric_only=True)
```

I've tried the above in 0.18.0 and couldn't seem to get it to work, so you can also do this to rank all float and int values:

```
>>> s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))].rank(pct=True).max()
1.0
```

It creates a boolean mask making sure each value is an int or float, and then ranks the filtered result.

Comment: I assumed it was from these non-numeric observations, but my intuition is that those entries would bound percentiles below 1 (e.g. if half the data is bad then my highest ranked observation would be .5). Anyway, good to know about the update.